# Must Powershell modules be placed in separate folders?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Using PowerShell 2.0

According to what I've read online, user-created powershell modules must each reside in their own directory. For example if I create a module called `MyModule.psm1` it must reside in a folder called `MyModule` and reside in any directory listed in `$env:PSModulePath`.

If I have many modules for a project, it seems silly to me to have to create a separate folder for each one. Is this *really* necessary? Why? Any elegant way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell modules can consist of more than one file, for instance for providing [multi-language help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or by [splitting the functionality into several files](http://msmvps.com/blogs/richardsiddaway/archive/2010/03/22/module-structure.aspx). So yes, it's necessary.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to just have the .psm1 file, you can import it by giving the path to the file itself rather than just the name of the module.

For example:

```
import-module c:\mymodules\folder\themodule.psm1
```

With this technique you can have as many modules as you want in the same folder.  I don't know that I'd recommend this, but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal, but you could create junctions ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) using [Sysinternals junction.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx). That would allow you to store all of the actual data in one folder, but reference it using different paths.

[[MSDN] Hard Links and Junctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Assume that you had three (3) stand-alone `.psm1` module files in a folder named `Modules` in your `$env:UserProfile\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` directory.

[image: Module Folder]

You can use several `junction.exe` commands to create junctions (links) that point to the "real" `Modules` folder on the filesystem.

```
$ModulePath = '{0}\Modules' -f (Split-Path -Path $Profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost -Parent);
junction.exe $ModulePath\Foo $ModulePath\Modules;
junction.exe $ModulePath\Bar $ModulePath\Modules;
junction.exe $ModulePath\Trevor $ModulePath\Modules;
```

[image: Junctions]

Here is what it looks like when you navigate into one of the junctions, for example, `Foo`.

[image: Junction]

As far as Windows PowerShell is concerned, you are in the `Foo` directory, which matches the `Foo.psm1` file name. It should ignore the rest of the files in that folder.

Now, you can run `Get-Module -ListAvailable`, and you should see a list of the modules in your user module directory.

[image: Get-Module -ListAvailable]